# Can I get the access mode of a `FILE*`?

Tags: c, macos, file-io, posix

I have to duplicate a `FILE*` in C on Mac OS X (using POSIX `int` file descriptors all the way is unfortunately out of question), so I came up with the following function:

```
static FILE* fdup(FILE* fp, const char* mode)
{
    int fd = fileno(fp);
    int duplicated = dup(fd);
    return fdopen(duplicated, mode);
}
```

It works very well, except it has that small ugly part where I ask for the file mode again, because `fdopen` apparently can't determine it itself.

This issue isn't critical, since basically, I'm just using it for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` (and obviously I know the access modes of those three). However, it *would* be more elegant if I didn't have to know it myself; and this is probably possible since the `dup` call doesn't need it.

How can I determine the access mode of a `FILE*` stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, but you can determine the mode for the underlying file descriptor:

```
int fd = fileno(f);
int accmode = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) & O_ACCMODE;
```

You can then choose an appropriate mode to pass to `fdopen` based on whether `accmode` is `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`.