# How to get the mode of a file descriptor?

Tags: c, filestream, file-descriptor, file-access, fcntl

I mean to use `fdopen`

```
FILE *fdopen(int fd, const char *mode);
```

In [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen), it is stated that "The mode of the stream (one of the values "r", "r+", "w", "w+", "a", "a+") must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor."
So I have to first know the mode of `fd` (which I guess is an `int`) to choose an appropriate `const char *mode` for the stream.

I understand I should use `fcntl`

```
int fcntl(int fd, int cmd);
```

to "manipulate file descriptor" (in the following, I quote from [this official source](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)).
It can operate on:

> **File descriptor flags**
>
> The following commands manipulate the flags associated with a file
>   descriptor. 
>   ...
>
> **File status flags**
>
> Each open file description has certain associated status flags,
>   initialized by open(2)...

(I wouldn't know the difference between the two.
Given that `fcntl` refers entirely to file descriptors, I guess the second title should be "File descriptor status flags", and thus we would have "flags" and "status flags"... confusing to me. I haven't seen any specification of this). I mention this in passing here, I am putting together a specific question on this.

From the description, I guess I should go for the latter.
In this case, when `cmd=F_GETFL`, the return value is "the file access mode and the file status flags". "The file status flags and their semantics are described in [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)".

Now I couldn't make sense of, after reading the sources cited:

1. What are all possible modes (`int`s) for the fd
2. Consequently, what are all combinations mode(fd) <-> mode(stream) that are "compatible".

I guess one should be able to put together two list and join with arrows.

Related:

[Can I get the access mode of a `FILE*`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328864/can-i-get-the-access-mode-of-a-file)

[Specification of file descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909916/specification-of-file-descriptors) (I asked this)

[How to catch file mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421107/how-to-catch-file-mode)

[I Wanna know the Internal Members of struct FILE, the latest ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209087/i-wanna-know-the-internal-members-of-struct-file-the-latest-ones)

[How to make sense of O_RDONLY = 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923703/how-to-make-sense-of-o-rdonly-0) (I asked this)

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Access-Modes.html

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Status-Flags.html#File-Status-Flags

Comment: The file "file-descriptor" flags are `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY` and `O_RDWR`. If you go back to the linked reference you should be able to figure out how to get this. And with the help of a [good `fopen` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) it shouldn't be to hard to match those to a `fopen` (and indeed `fdopen`) mode string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Thanks. I did go back, several times, and I could not figure that out. That is why I come here and ask, and I am eager to see answers. It might be hidden in plain sight, at least for me.

Comment: Use `F_GETFL` to get the flags, which should include the open-mode (which might need some bitwise masking to get out).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - As posted in the OP, I got to the point of using `F_GETFL`, and knowing it includes the open-mode. But I still couldn't put together the simple descriptive lists which are the target of the question, and the connection between them.

Comment: `O_READ` is `"r"`. `O_WRITE` is `"w"` or `"a"` (depending on where you want to write to the file). `O_RDWR` could be any of the other read-write strings, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - I don't seem to have `O_READ`, even if I am using gcc and this https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Access-Modes.html. And I do have `O_ACCMODE`, in `fcntl-linux.h`.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, I meant `O_RDONLY` and `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Please check the table posted by Tony Tannous and my answer. They provide interesting info, which I guess it was not quite obvious to infer from the pages I had found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After learning from answers and comments, here and in [How to make sense of O_RDONLY = 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923703/how-to-make-sense-of-o-rdonly-0), I put together code below.
From there, I obtained the following info about file descriptor status "*words*" (I wouldn't like to use the term "*flags*", see Note below, taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923703/how-to-make-sense-of-o-rdonly-0#comment109524913_61923919)) and file opening *mode*s.

```
*** Flag                       O_RDONLY =     0 =            0 = x0000
*** Flag                       O_WRONLY =     1 =            1 = x0001
*** Flag                         O_RDWR =     2 =           10 = x0002
*** Flag                        O_CREAT =    64 =      1000000 = x0040
*** Flag                        O_TRUNC =   512 =   1000000000 = x0200
*** Flag                       O_APPEND =  1024 =  10000000000 = x0400
*** Flag   O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC =   577 =   1001000001 = x0241
*** Flag  O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND =  1089 =  10001000001 = x0441
*** Flag     O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC =   578 =   1001000010 = x0242
*** Flag    O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND =  1090 =  10001000010 = x0442
*** Mode  r  F_GETFL -> 32768 = 1000000000000000 = x8000
*** Mode  w  F_GETFL -> 32769 = 1000000000000001 = x8001
*** Mode  a  F_GETFL -> 33793 = 1000010000000001 = x8401
*** Mode r+  F_GETFL -> 32770 = 1000000000000010 = x8002
*** Mode w+  F_GETFL -> 32770 = 1000000000000010 = x8002
*** Mode a+  F_GETFL -> 33794 = 1000010000000010 = x8402
```

Numbers in the three columns are in decimal, binary and hex.
Looking for the "strange" `x8000`, I found in `fcntl-linux.h`

```
# ifdef __USE_GNU
...
#  define AT_RECURSIVE      0x8000  /* Apply to the entire subtree.  */
...
# endif
```

So, except for that *flag*, present in all *mode*s, the association would be

```
r   <->  O_RDONLY
w   <->  O_WRONLY
a   <->  O_WRONLY | O_APPEND
r+  <->  O_RDWR
w+  <->  O_RDWR
a+  <->  O_RDWR | O_APPEND
```

Now this provides a couple of intriguing findings to me:

1. The list does not coincide with [the table given by Tony Tannous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61909773/2707864).
2. The *word* for `r+` is the same as for `w+`.
   This provides a challenge for the coder, as to which mode to use with `fdopen` when the word is `O_RDWR` (both `r+` and `w+` would be ok).
   As per [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), I expected `w+` to have also `O_CREAT` (as in the table mentioned above).
   I also expected `w` to have it.
3. To write completely portable code, it seems that whenever using `fdopen` one has to write code as I wrote to automatically find the connection *mode* <-> *word*.
   (actually, part of the work I did was a manual identification, and further code is needed).

**EDIT**:
The explanation for points 1 and 2 as per comments is that the table shows the match between `fopen` modes and `open` flags, i.e., during creation.
But what I obtained with `fcntl` is the flags persistent *after* creation, not those used *during* creation.
As also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909916/specification-of-file-descriptors), `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` belong to the category of *File creation flags* and thus are not persistent.
On the other hand, `O_APPEND` belongs to the category *File status flags* and is persistent.
"The distinction between these two groups of flags is that the *file creation flags* affect the semantics of the open operation itself, while the *file status flags* affect the semantics of subsequent I/O operations." [[ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)]

**Note**:
The [man page for open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) first describes the file access modes, and then adds "In addition, zero or more file creation flags and file status flags can be bitwise-or'd in flags...." But it (correctly) does not mention that file access mode can be bitwise operated on. For me, the word "flag" is an absolute misnomer, and misleading.

---

**Code** (any function `to_binary` to get the binary form can be used):

```
int main() {
    const char fname[100] = "test.txt";
    const char modes[][4] = { "r", "w", "a", "r+", "w+", "a+" };
    const size_t nmodes = sizeof(modes) / sizeof(modes[0]);
    const int flags[] = { O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, O_RDWR, O_CREAT, O_TRUNC, O_APPEND,
            O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,
            O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND,
            O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC,
            O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND
    };
    const char flags_str[][100] = { "O_RDONLY", "O_WRONLY", "O_RDWR", "O_CREAT", "O_TRUNC", "O_APPEND",
            "O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC",
            "O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND",
            "O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC",
            "O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND"
    };
    const size_t nflags = sizeof(flags) / sizeof(flags[0]);
    for (size_t iflag = 0 ; iflag < nflags ; iflag++) {
        const int flag = flags[iflag];
        const char * flag_str = flags_str[iflag];
        char nbin[33];
        to_binary(flag, nbin);
        printf( "*** Flag %30s = %5d = %12s = x%04x\n", flag_str, flag, nbin, flag);
    }
    for (size_t imode = 0 ; imode < nmodes ; imode++) {
        const char * mode = modes[imode];
        FILE * fp1 = fopen(fname, mode);
        int fd1 = fileno(fp1);
        int retval = fcntl(fd1, F_GETFL);
        char nbin[33];
        to_binary(retval, nbin);
        printf( "*** Mode %2s  F_GETFL -> %5d = %12s = x%04x", mode, retval, nbin, retval);
        fclose(fp1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer, I will soon remove my answer.  For future readers who wonder what table I was refering to, it can be found in [fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) man page.

Comment: Though w+ should create file if not exist... Open for reading and writing, I'd expect O_CREAT. `The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.` Obtained from [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) source as well. Maybe tag Barmar? `w+` creates file when not exist. Tested.

Comment: **To write completely portable code, it seems that whenever using fdopen one has to write code as I wrote to automatically find the connection mode** Most of the time you know a priori how you're going to use the file, whether for reading or writing, you don't need to get the mode dynamically.

Comment: @TonyTannous - I'd suggest you don't remove the answer. Given it is official info, I think  it may be useful for others too. Then whoever reads it will have to get the big picture by reading the rest of the answers/comments.

Comment: @Barmar - Agreed. What do you think about the two other points?

Comment: The distinction between `r+` and `w+` matters in `fopen()`, but not `fdopen()`. `O_CREAT` and `O_TRUNC` only affect what `open()` does while it's opening the file, they don't have any persistent effect on the descriptor.

Comment: @Barmar - Your comment seems to completely bridge the gap between what I found and the table posted by Tony... great!
Would you post it as an answer?

Comment: @Barmar - As for point 1, one may well need to write functions that would be targeted for any mode (I need something like this), and in those cases this is still a (serious?) problem/workload.
Do you see any way around this?

Comment: Can you give examples? This is the whole reason why `fdopen()` has the mode argument, because it can't be inferred automatically.

Comment: So you should just pass that requirement along in your functions.

Comment: @Barmar - Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

---

From [fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) you can check how they correlate with `w+` `r` etc...

[image]

Comment: What it seems the OP is asking about is the open mode flags (e.g. `O_RDWR` etc.) not the file-type or protection flags which are available from `st_mode`. This is to match is against a corresponding mode-string for `fdopen`.

Comment: Bingo!! That table, from an official source, is exactly what I was looking for. The man page I happen to hit doesn't have the table!

Comment: Note that `O_RDONLY` (e.g.) is not meant to be used for bitwise operations, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61923919/2707864. Actually, I think that your `if (mode & O_RDONLY)` will not behave as you expect.
You may double check and fix this, for the benefit of the community.

Comment: Please check the answer I added, its findings do not seem to completely agree with the table.