# How to make sense of O_RDONLY = 0?

Tags: c, file-descriptor, fcntl, bitflags

I am dealing with file status flags.
Among test I performed, I found

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fcntl.h"

int main() {
    const int flag = O_RDONLY;
    printf( "*** Flag O_RDONLY = %5d\n", flag);
    return 0;
}
```

produces this output

```
*** Flag O_RDONLY =     0
```

which is fully consistent with

```
#define O_RDONLY         00
```

from `fcntl-linux.h`.

**How can the value zero be used as a flag?**

I expect an "atomic" flag to be `2^n` (`n>=1`), and "composite" flags (like `O_ACCMODE`) to be simply the sum of several atomic flags (which is the same as bitwise-or'ing those atomic flags).
As far as I understand, I cannot "detect" anything, and such flag cannot be ever set.
A bitwise-and'ed expression like `(stat & O_RDONLY)` will always be false.

Related:

[How to get the mode of a file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909358/how-to-get-the-mode-of-a-file-descriptor) (I asked this)

Comment: If you can do nothing else with a file what remains?

Comment: The file status flags are not a bit mask. They're just 3 alternative options: O_RDONLY = 0, O_WRONLY = 1, O_RDWR = 2

Comment: values for o_flags are constructed using bitwise-inclusive OR

Comment: @AndreasDM No they aren't. `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY != O_RDWR`

Comment: True: *`_O_RDONLY` Opens a file for reading only. Cannot be specified with `_O_RDWR` or `_O_WRONLY`*.

Comment: @Barmar: to my pain when I need a handle to something I can't read or write (for `fstat()` or `fchdir()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although these are called flags in the documentation, these three are not actually atomic flags that can be combined like the rest. They're mutually exclusive alternative values for the `O_ACCMODE` bits. You don't use `stat & RDONLY` to test for it, you use `(stat & O_ACCMODE) == O_RDONLY`.

Comment: Great!
Actually, the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html first describes the file access modes, and then adds "In addition, zero or more file creation flags and file status flags can be bitwise-or'd in flags...."
But it does not mention that file access mode can be bitwise operated on.
For me, the word "flag" is an absolute misnomer, and misleading.

Comment: Related, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909358/how-to-get-the-mode-of-a-file-descriptor/61909773 and give your insight?